# Why when changing the comboBox item it's not changing the time counting in the correct way?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

comboBox selectedindexchanged event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateTime = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            xpProgressBar1.Position = 0;
            counter = 0;
            panel1.Select();
        }
```

Update method:

```
public void Update()
        {
            counter += 1;
            int position = (int)Math.Round((counter / updateTime) * 100);
            xpProgressBar1.Text = counter.ToString() + " %";
            xpProgressBar1.Position = position;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

Timer tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Update();
        }
```

In the combBox by default it's on the first item the number 10 then i can change and select the item with the number 30,50,60,120,300 and all this values are in seconds.

The timer1 interval is set to 1000

The problem is when it's on 10 by default when running the program or if i change it back to 10 in the comboBox it's working good. What it does it's counting 10 seconds and updating the progressBar(xpProgressBar1) by 10's i mean each second the progressBar move by 10 percentages. So after 10 seconds it's getting to 100 percentages.

But when i change the comboBox to the second item to 30 it should count now 30 seconds untill 100%

So i'm not sure in what steps it should move and how to do it. Same if i change it to 120 then it should move progress 120 seconds and again i'm not sure what steps and how to do it so it will get to 100%

What it does now for example if i change it to 120 i see it start counting to 120 by steps of 1 but then when it's getting to 10% it's jumping back to the start and not continue.

It should keep counting the whole 120 seconds untill 100%

If i change it to 30 i see it also counting by steps of 1 each time but again in 10% it's jumping to the start and not continue.

When it's on 10 it's counting by steps of 10 untill 100% so i wonder what should i do and how in the others if it's on 120 to step by 120 ? not logic. So tmake them all to step by 1 also the when it's on 10 ? And again how to do it so it will not stop a 10% and start over again.

Now i changed in the Update method the line if (counter == 10) to:

```
if (counter == updateTime)
```

So now if i change in the comboBox select 120 it will count in steps of 1 untill 120 but now when it will get the progressBar to 100% it will keep counting untill 120.

There is no sync between the 120 seconds and the 100% of the progressBar.

EDIT

The Update method:

```
private int _updateCounter;
        public void Update()
        {
            counter += 1;
            xpProgressBar1.Text = counter.ToString() + " %";
            xpProgressBar1.Position = _updateCounter++ * 10;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }

                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not set xpProgressBar1.Maximum = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())? That way xpProgressBar1.Position=counter and you can avoid the headache of setting the percentage

Comment: Are `counter` and other shared variables marked volatile? Depending on how you instantiate the timer, you may be running the code on different threads and potentially hitting a context cache instead of the in-memory value

Comment: I've deleted my earlier answer.  You aren't showing enough of your code to deal with possible side effects from other parts of your code.  Additionally, you are stopping the timer based on the status of a background worker, but are controlling the progress bar through a discrete set of counters.   You can't guarantee a run from 0-100 with that set up.  If you don't know how long your code will take I think there's a setting that will just have the progress bar spin without worrying about percentage to show unknown progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [prescaler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescaler) (frequency divider). You have single clock source (`Timer`) with *fastest* frequency using which you can achieve needed frequencies by skipping certain calls (events).

All you miss is that *skipping*:

```
private int _timer1Ticks;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_timer1Ticks++ >= int.Parse(comboBox1.Text) / 10)
    {
        _timer1Ticks = 0;
        Update();
    }
}
```

This way `Update` will be called exactly `10` times, disregard of combobox selection.

And to calculate progress:

```
private int _updateCounter;
public void Update()
{
    xpProgressBar1.Position = _updateCounter++ * 10;
    ...
    // do not forget to stop timer
    if(_updateCounter == 10)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        _updateCounter = 0; // add some cleanup if using timer more than once
        _timer1Ticks = 0;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sinatr i tried this way it's working slow now the counting didnt start one my program start i mean the timer and in the end for example if it set to 10 it's getting to 10 but only 90% then start counting again but not reseting the progressBar.

Comment: Sinatr look at my question please i added the Update method how it look like now and i changed the timer1 tick event exactly to what you wrote but it's not working good.